# Android change locale programmatically doesn't update for drawables

Tags: android, resources, local

I am changing the local of my application programmatically using:

```
 private static void updateResources(Context context, int language) {
    String languageToLoad;
    if (language == 2)
        languageToLoad = "ar";
    else
        languageToLoad = "en";
    locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}
```

The direction of the layout and the string resources changes according to the new locale, BUT drawable resources don't change unless I restart the app manually, I am recreating the activity using:

```
activity.recreate()
```

Comment: You can't dynamically change or update any resources.

Comment: i don't wan't to change the resource , i want to change the loaded resource

Comment: `I am recreating the activity using: activity.recreate()` Consider finishing and restarting your Activity.

Comment: If I am not wrong, initially at the start of the app you have Resource1 and then by calling a method you want to change the Resource1 to Resource2, which is not possible dear. Better to finish (exit) the app and show a toast to user to start the app again.

Comment: @Jack You can finish and restart the single Activity.

Comment: @Rotwang recreate() actually finish the activity and then start it again. And the questioner said he did the same thing.

Comment: @Jack i am not sure if you understand me right, but i have an image drawable (en) and image drawable (ar) , what i need to do is when i change the locale of my application from en to ar "Arabic" then change the loaded drawable where ever it used (like image views)

Comment: @Raafat See i understood your point and this is what I am saying. You can't switch between the different resources files dynamically. You need to finish the activity (exit the app) and then show a toast to the user to restart the app again.

Comment: @Jack will .. thanks a lot .. i will use this solution..

Comment: @CopsOnRoad If we have change the app language then if we have some searching option within app, and if we search in that then, how app will show data, should we develop some different database for each language or some android code setting is there so that app could show data according to search ?

Comment: `if we change the app language`, how are you changing app language, is it using phone settings or within the app?